Doctrine Entity is not complete in second PHP Instance
We are facing a really strange Error. We are creating a Task Entity with Doctrine and saving it to the Database:
$task = $taskService->findById(1);
$task->setEmail($email); // Email Entity
$entityManager->persist($task);
$entityManager->flush();

After that we are creating a new RabbitMQ Message that only contains the id of the task. The Listener that is called by the consumer script loads the task:
$task = $taskService->findById($taskId);

The strange thing is, at this point $task does not allways contain the email.
It appears that if the Listener receives the first taskId after the Worker has been started $task has the email, every subsequent call from the Worker to the Listener does not contain the email. The taskId changes with every Call to the Listener.
As soon as we add a sleep(1); at the beginning of the listener $task always contains the email.
The Worker script runs independently and has its own Doctrine Instance.
Update: Calling clear() on the EntityManager after each Listener also solves the problem.

Are the "Listener" & "Worker" part of some 3rd party library or framework ? Are you doing synchronous or asynchronous task processing ?

@AymDev The only library involved in that case is Doctrine. The Task processing is async (RabbitMQ)
